# In R, A bin contains five components from supplier A, three from supplier B, and two from supplier C

Tags: r

A bin contains five components from supplier A, three from supplier B, and two
from supplier C. If three of the components are randomly selected for testing,
what is the probability that each supplier would have at least one component
tested?

Please, I need help. I stopped here, and I could not proceed.

```
bin<-  function()
{
  x <- sample(c(rep('A',5),rep('B',3),rep('C',2)),3,replace =F)
  length(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The check part could be better

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

bin<-  function(...){
  components <- sample(c(rep('A',5),rep('B',3),rep('C',2)),3,replace =F)
  
  #Chek if the sample contains A, B and C
  check<-
  map(c("A","B","C"),.f = function(x)sum(str_detect(components,x))>0) %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    sum()
  
  if(check == 3){
    out <- 1
  }else{
    out <- 0
  }
  return(out)
}

mean(replicate(n = 10000,expr = bin()))
[1] 0.2419
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bin <-  function()
{
  x <- sample(c(rep('A',5),rep('B',3),rep('C',2)),3,replace =F)
  length(unique(x))
}

mean(replicate(10000,sum(bin()==3)))
```